# Factoring rationals from equation based on digit complexity?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, factorization

Consider an equation of the following type:

```
( poly = (3 x)/35 + (6 y)/7 ) == 0
```

If we apply the command `Factor` to this expression, we get

```
poly//Factor
```

> `3/35 (x + 10 y)`

which would suggest to divide out the factor `3/35`. However, doing the factorization manually, we can also find the following shape

> `3/7 (1/5 x + 2 y)`

Which suggests to divide out `3/7`. I personally prefer the latter since the remaining coefficients are only one digit numbers `1/5` and `2`, while the factorized result produced by Mathematica involves a coefficient `10` with two digits and therefore higher complexity. If we go to more complicated examples where rationals might involve integers with hundreds of digits, I would prefer the factorization to leave behind coefficients with numerators and denominators containing as little amount of digits as possible. Is there a way to tell Mathematica to factorize based on number of digits instead of the standard procedure? Or maybe one can implement such a factorization routine in a convenient way? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Please consider changing `The latter is preferred ` by `I prefer the latter` :)

Comment: I have done as you suggest! :)

Comment: @Kagaratsch, take a look at one approach: `1/7 Simplify[poly*7]`